# Using Manage_External_Storage with .net Maui

Tags: c#, android, maui

So i am Creating an android app with .net Maui, that reads an XML file from my Documents(`/storage/emulated/0/Documents`) folder. The App is 100% capable of generating its own XML file to ensure that it always exists. However if i Replace the XML the Application crashes with an access denied execption. I believe this is due to the Fact that i am Using Storage_Read and Storage_Write Permissions instead of Manage_External_Storage. I am now Looking for a workaround to geting that permission since .net maui has not yet updated its permission  system to API level 34.

The code That Requests Permissions:

```
PermissionStatus lReadStatus = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();  
PermissionStatus lWriteStatus =await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
```

My Android Manifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Can you provide more infos, especially about how you save your xml file ? I've met a similar issue, maybe checking [my answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78043220/correct-file-saving-path-on-a-maui-multiplatform-app) might help you ?

Comment: Dont let your application crash by catching that exception. If there is an exception display a toast to the user saying so.

Comment: Those read and write permissions are only needed for Android 12 and below.

Comment: The read permission never works for files not created by your app.

Comment: `Manage_External_Storage. I am now Looking for a workaround to geting that permission since .net maui has not yet updated its permission system to API level 34.` Manage external storage is there since Android 11.  Has nothing to do with SDK 34.

Comment: Use storage access framework to let the user select the file. Not a single permission needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.