Pack 'Microsoft.Android.Ref.31' was not present in workload manifests
We need to target Android v31 (NOT v34). What do we need to do in order to target Android v31 in our Maui app?  All attempts at this are failing.
I have 31 set in the AndroidManifest.xml as the target version, but I think Visual Studio is overriding it due to the v34 setting in the project file, which is NOT possible to change for some reason.
If we attempt to build with TargetFrameworks set to "net8.0-android31.0" in the projects property file like this:
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android31.0</TargetFrameworks>

we get this error:
**error NETSDK1181: Error getting pack version: Pack 'Microsoft.Android.Ref.31' was not present in workload manifests.**

I read that workloads can be installed using
dotnet workload install <workloadId>

But I have NO idea what workloadId to use for Android v31 and I cannot find any documentation on this anywhere.
The SDK for 31 is installed, which I can verify with the Android SDK Manager, but this seems to make no difference.
Any help with a solution to this would be much appreciated.


We need to target Android v31 (NOT v34). What do we need to do in order to target Android v31 in our Maui app?

You can just use the <uses-sdk> tag in the AndroidManifest.xml to do that:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
          android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

The code above will make your app target android 31 but can still run on android 34.

If we attempt to build with TargetFrameworks set to "net8.0-android31.0" in the projects property file like this:

Please check the official document about OS version in TFMs. And I also tried it and add <TargetPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">30</TargetPlatformVersion> into the csproj file.
I get the following error in both ways:

31.0 is not a valid TargetPlatformVersion for Android. Valid versions include: 34.0

The .net8.0 can only set te target android framework version as 34. In addition, the target framework version just decides the Android SDK version when you code and compile.

Zhang: I have specified 31 as the target in the manifest, but the behavior is more like 34.  For example, when calling the Permissions API, I never see a prompt for storage options when running the app.  Do you know how I can verify what was actually built?
Also:  If I build for .NET 7 (instead of 8) will I be able to target 31 in the project?

The api is depend on the device android version not the app's target version. And the storage permission has been removed since android 13.0. No matter what version your app target, the prompt will not show on android 13 and higher version. Can you explain why do you need the storage permission? The android 13 and higher version use new media permission. @DAConsulting

And then if you want to create file. You can refer to my old answer.

Hi Liyun Zhang:  Yes.  I realized after more investigation that those permissions have been removed in later Android versions.  I did find an answser to the storage problem in this SO article:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78226250/using-manage-external-storage-with-net-maui.

PS:  We need to keep certain files outside the app's private folder for logging and trouble shooting purposes.  It is mandatory that we have the ability to create files this way so that users can easily access them.   It also guarantees the ability to upgrade (or completely uninstall and reinstall) without losing the app data.   Google has become too restrictive, IMHO.

Did you mean you used the manage external storage permission and resolved this issue? @DAConsulting

Zhang : Sorry for the confusion.  At first, I was attempting to target a lower Android version in order to get around the issues created by Google eliminating (nuetralizing) the storage permissions.  While doing so, I found the SO article on manage external storage - which made it possible to do what I needed under Android 34.  So the issue of targeting a lower android version is no longer needed for us.  Thanks!

All right, glad to know you have resolved this problem. @DAConsulting
